# Building dict in loop adds values to wrong keys

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
data = open(filename).readlines()
result = {}
for d in data:
    res[d[0:11]] = d
```

Each line in data looks like so and there are 251 with 2 different "keys" in the first 11 characters:

```
205583620002008TAVG  420  M  400  M 1140  M 1590  M 2160  M 2400  M 3030  M 2840  M 2570  M 2070  M 1320  M  750  M
205583620002009TAVG  380  M  890  M 1060  M 1630  M 2190  M 2620  M 2880  M 2790  M 2500  M 2130  M 1210  M  640  M
205583620002010TAVG  530  M  750  M  930  M 1280  M 2080  M 2380  M 2890  M 3070  M 2620  M 1920  M 1400  M  790  M
205583620002011TAVG  150  M  600  M  930  M 1600  M 2160  M 2430  M 3000  M 2790  M 2430  M 1910  M 1670  M  650  M
205583620002012TAVG  470  M  440  M  950  M 1750  M 2130  M 2430  M 2970  M 2900  M 2370  M 1980  M 1220  M  630  M
205583620002013TAVG  460  M  680  M 1100  M 1530  M 2130  M 2410  M 3200  M 3100  M-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999 XM
205583620002014TAVG-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XP-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC
205583620002015TAVG-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XC-9999 XK-9999 XP-9999   -9999   -9999   
210476000001930TAVG  153  0  343  0  593  0 1033  0 1463  0 1893  0 2493  0 2583  0 2023  0 1483  0  873  0  473  0
210476000001931TAVG  203  0   73  0  473  0  833  0 1383  0 1823  0 2043  0 2513  0 2003  0 1413  0 1033  0  543  0
210476000001932TAVG  433  0  243  0  403  0  933  0 1503  0 1833  0 2353  0 2493  0 2043  0 1393  0  963  0  583  0
210476000001933TAVG  133  0   53  0  213  0  953  0 1553  0 1983  0 2543  0 2543  0 2043  0 1403  0  973  0  503  0
210476000001934TAVG  103  0  153  0  333  0  843  0 1493  0 1933  0 2243  0 2353  0 1983  0 1353  0  863  0  523  0
210476000001935TAVG  243  0  273  0  503  0  983  0 1453  0 1893  0 2303  0 2343  0 2053  0 1473  0  993  0  453  0
210476000001936TAVG   -7  0   33  0  223  0  903  0 1433  0 1983  0 2293  0 2383  0 2153  0 1443  0  913  0  573  0
```

The keys output is this:

```
print res.keys()
>['20558362000', '21047600000']
```

And to check the result I have 3 prints:

```
print len(res.values())
print len(res.values()[0])
print len(res.values()[1])
```

My expected output is:

```
2
165
86
```

But I end up with:

```
2
116
116
```

It's pretty clear to me that it adds the same values to both keys, but I don't understand why.
If anyone could clarify with or without a working code strip it would help a lot.

Comment: You need to incude what `data` looks like. Without it, expected outputs are worth nothing...

Comment: If you provide a *complete and runnable* example that demonstrates the problem it's easy to answer such questions. In this case not providing all information makes the question simply impossible to answer since the output depends on a file that we don't have and thus cannot check why the result isn't the one you expected.

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Alright i added a line from the data file. I suppose you don't need the 250 nearly identical ones? (Not sarcastic, I'm a fairly new user)

Comment: yes, add a few at least please

Comment: btw, why is the line indented? prefixed with spaces? if so, the slice may be wrong...

Comment: I have tested the slice multiple times. The line is indented because I'm not sure how to make it look nice in stack overflow.

Comment: What is the output of `print(res.keys())`?

Comment: so it does look like quite a few lines have the very same prefix...

Comment: I added the keys printed to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
res[d[0:11]] = d
```

the entry in the `dict` gets overwritten, and each line has a length of 116 characters. So a

```
print len(res.values()[0])
```

returns the length of a single line, not a number of elements.

You need to so something like this:

```
for d in data:
    key = d[0:11]
    if key in res:
        res[key].append(d)
    else:
        res[key] = [d]
```

Checkout [defaultkey](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Comment: I see. I need to somehow append these together so I get all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: the first 10 characters of the string that you use as the key(s) are all the same in your example, so the value for the key keeps on being reset !

Use this code as a proof (substitute by the name of your `filename`):

```
filename = 'test.dat'
data = open(filename).readlines()
result = {}
for d in data:
    key = d[0:11]
    if key in result:
        print  'key {key} already in {dict}'.format(key=key, dict=result)
    result[key] = d

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect multiple lines you should store them in a sequence (preferably list). Right now you are overwriting previously stored line with new one (that's what `res[d[0:11]] = d` does).

Possible solution:

```
data = open(filename).readlines()
result = {}
for d in data:
    try:
        res[d[0:11]].append(d)
    except KeyError:
        res[d[0:11]] = [d]
```